# замена return на yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, yield

Есть такая функция, задача которой получить номер запроса на экспорт данных. После получения номеру хочу в этой же функции передать данное значение в следующий запрос и получить сами данные. Проблема в том, что оператор "return" ,как оказалось после своего выполнения завершает функцию. Хочу заменить его на оператор "yield", но к сожалению когда я его меняю все вообще перестает работать и не выполняется совсем ничего. Не понимаю в чем проблема.
Подскажите, как правильно заменить в данном коде return на yield и с его помощью передать зачение в переменную.

```
    print('Получаем Export_id')
    today_str = DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    #получаем export_id 
    response = requests.get(BASE_URL_EXPORT_ID, params=params_export_id)
    result = response.json()
    print (result)
    #сохраняю данные для 2 части запроса :)
    export_id = result['info']['export_id']
    return export_id
    
    #получаю сами данные
    response1 = requests.get(BASE_URL_DATA, params=params_data)
    result1 = response1.json()
    print(response1.request.url)
    #Отбираю нужные ключи из запроса
    print(result1)
    a = result1['info']['fields']
    b = result1['info']['items']
    #Делаю красиво :)
    a_and_b = [dict(zip(a, x)) for x in b]
    q = (json.dumps(a_and_b, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
    print(q)
#export_id = run()
sched = BlockingScheduler()

sched.add_job(run, 'cron', month='1-12', day='1-31', hour=20, minute=29)

sched.start()

export_id = run()
```

Comment: @andreymal, добавил часть кода

Comment: А каков практический смысл возвращения export_id в середине функции? Почему бы его не вернуть в конце вместе с другими данными?

Comment: @andreymal, я беру из ее значение и передаю во второй запрос. эти данные нужны для получения информации

Comment: Почему бы не сделать отдельную специальную функцию для получения export_id в таком случае? А потом этот export_id передавать в другие функции для получения информации

Comment: @andreymal Кажется, я так и предлагал автору вопроса в предыдущем его вопросе из которого вырос этот - просто сделать функцию, которая будет вызывать сначала одну функцию, потом другую. И эту функцию вешать на шедулер.

Comment: тут вызов функции нужен колбэком а не елд с ретурном

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Остановитесь.**

Вы не совсем понимаете, что такое функции, и как использовать `return` и `yield` в Питоне. Поэтому вопрос поставили неверный.

Проблема ваша не в `yield`, а в дизайне кода. Функция должна делать одну и только одну вещь. Вы же спрашиваете, как сделать так, чтобы функция которая видимо уже делает слишком много, делала ещё больше.

Могу посоветовать три вещи:

1. Переформулировать вопрос. Вы объясняете, *как* вы что-то хотите сделать. Объясните лучше *что* вы хотите сделать.
2. Почитайте книги по Питону, чтобы иметь определенные базы. Без этого, процесс обучения будет очень долгим. Зачем вам это?
3. Почитайте общие книги по программированию, стилю и дизайну кода.